# How to prevent horizontal containers from overlapping or moving when screen size is reduced?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to align two boxes next to each other like the following. This works as shown below until you shrink the screen size. Then the items get jumbled up as shown in the second picture.

[image]

[image]

The code I am using is the following:

**CSS**

```
#leftbox { 
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 35%;
  float:left;    
} 

#rightbox { 
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 35%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float:right;
}
```

Everything is wrapped in this container:

```
.mycontainer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 104px 0 24px 0;
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "leftbox">
        <a target="_blank" href="link" style="text-decoration: none">
          <code>
           <img src="github.png" height="25" width="25"/>
          </code>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id = "rightbox">
        <a target="_blank" href="link" style="text-decoration: none">
          <code>
           <img src="linkedin.png" height="25" width="25"/>
          </code>
        </a>
      </div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you give us more context? With the code you have shown here, it only happens when the screen is less than 250px, which is smaller than any device screen. Is this in a grid for example? The big problem is that you have set margins of 35% which is taking up too much space in certain circumstances. What is the reason for these margins? If you let us know what you are trying to achieve, we can offer a better answer

Comment: @FluffyKitten I am sorry, I want the two boxes centered on the screen next to each other. The above code works until the screen gets shrunk such as on a mobile device

Comment: Is this is a grid? As I said, it only becomes a problem at < 250px which is smaller than any mobile. Can you show us the HTML and CSS for the container element that this is in?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I just learned HTML and CSS this weekend, so I don't know all of the terminologies, but I updated the question with the container that the elements are wrapped in. Thank you for all of the help!

Comment: No problem, as long as you can give us the info we ask for, we should be able to help. You'll pick it us as you go along. Have fun learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your margins and px are making everything too exact. They're overlapping because the boxes are still following the margin rules. To make it flexible, use flexbox.

Add:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Your code -->
</div>
```

Make this your css:

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
  
 #leftbox, #rightbox { 
    margin: 3% 5%;
}
```

If you want the boxes to not use the whole screen, add a `width: 80vw;` or whatever you need to the container. Try not using pixels. Ideally vw, vh, rem, or %.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pixels it's good practice to use view width and view height as your unit unless you want to specifically set pixels.
So your CSS should look something like this:

margin-top: 3vh;
margin-right: 2vw;

and so on. otherwise you could manually set the divs to adjust to screen size via the @media call

Comment: I tried changing the margins, however that didn't work. On small screens, they still overlap. Can you provide an example of using @media call, I am still new to this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show how it works in their specific case and why it solves their problem. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Also, whether you should use `vw` or another unit is totally project dependent, so I wouldn't say the margins "should" look like anything yet until we know more about what the OP is trying to achieve.